# Expand function isn't properly expanding for my Graph

Tags: c++, graph, expand

Does anyone see something overtly wrong with my expand function below? I've included the private section of the class and my vertex_node struct to give some context. I'm not sure why it isn't expanding properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private:

//list is pointers to vertex nodes;

struct vertex_node {
            string name;
            set <string> edges;
};

vertex_node **list;

void Graph:: expand()   
{   

    int new_cap = capacity * 2+1;
    //creates new larger array 
    vertex_node **larger_array = new vertex_node*[new_cap];

    //loop through all elements of old array
    for(int i = 0; i<capacity; i++){
        if(list[i] != NULL){

        //rehash each element and place it in new array
        int a = hash_string(list[i]->name) % new_cap;   

        larger_array[a]         = new vertex_node;
        larger_array[a]->name   = list[i] -> name;
        larger_array[a]->edges  = list[i] -> edges;
    }

    //delete old list
    delete[] list;
    list = larger_array;
    capacity = new_cap;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `capacity` and how is it initialized? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: `delete[] list` is executed while iterating `i` through each element of `list`, once each iteration, it is also assigned to larger_array, which is deleted the next iteration.  But maybe the real code wasn't properly copied over.

Comment: By the way, when you allocate the memory `new` will not initialize it, if there's a default constructor it will be called, but pointers and other native types (like e.g. `int` or `double`) don't have default constructor. That means the pointers in the array you allocate will have *indeterminate* values and give you *undefined behavior* when you have the check `list[i] != NULL`. I recommend you do e.g. `new vertex_node*[new_cap](nullptr)` to initialize all pointers to a null pointer. And do the same for the initial allocation.

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes, why use your own memory management instead of using e.g. `std::vector`? And what happens if two nodes give you the same hash?

Comment: Also, once you fix it so the pointers in `list` aren't mostly uninitialized data, you should make sure you delete each list element before deleting `list` itself (like `delete list[i];` during the iteration).

Comment: Can someone provide an example of what it should look like instead? Your feedback is great but I'm just slightly confused as to what it should look like

Comment: `if(list[i] != NULL){....` and then you do a `delete[] list` after copying out just the 1st element which effectively invalidates the whole array. You should be just doing `delete list[i]` each time within the `for` loop and then once the whole `for` loop is done you need to do a `delete[] list`

Answer (score 1):

as I mentioned in my comment above you're invalidating the whole array at the end of the 1st iteration. Your attempt at avoiding a memory leak is commendable but it has to be done in 2 places.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<capacity; i++){
            if(list[i] != NULL){

            //rehash each element and place it in new array
            int a = hash_string(list[i]->name) % new_cap;   

            larger_array[a]         = new vertex_node;
            larger_array[a]->name   = list[i] -> name;
            larger_array[a]->edges  = list[i] -> edges;
        }

        //clean up every memory location once you're done with it
        delete list[i];
        list = larger_array;
        capacity = new_cap;
        }
   //clean the whole array at the very end
    delete[] list;
```